# How to remove ACL from a directory and back to usual access control?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl

I accidentally added extended permission using setfacl, so how can i remove it?

I successfully set extended permission with

```
setfacl -R u:user2:wrx /tmp
```

and I have tried to remove with instructed by man page

```
setfacl -R -x u:user2:wrx /tmp
```

But not success in removing this permission

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

Here is how:

```
setfacl -bn foobar
```

from source:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339765/how-to-remove-acl-from-a-directory-and-back-to-usual-access-control

Comment: Wow I hunted everywhere and all I found was -x argument. which failed!